# Microsoft graph search within drive or folder hierarchy returns nothing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm doing search in drive and folder hierarchy in the graph explorer logged in as myself and having granted consent and nothing is being returned.

On this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0

It says:
"Search the hierarchy of items for items matching a query. You can search within a folder hierarchy, a whole drive, or files shared with the current user."

When I do search based on what the user can access documented in this section "Searching for items a user can access" then I get results. But if I specify the root or some other folder then the search returns nothing, i.e. this works:

/me/drive/search(q='{search-query}')

but these return nothing even though I'm searching within my drive and have items in my drive owned by me that meet the search criteria:

/me/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')

/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')

/drives/{drive-id}/items/{folder-id}/search(q='{search-text}')

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? When I get the results from the search on what I can see, the results clearly show that the results are from my drive. And as I mentioned those items are owned by me.

Update: strange but testing again today, the root and folder search seem to be working now. We're going t continue to monitor the results.

Regards,
LT

Comment: Beware https://stackoverflow.com/q/70083670/685796

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the following request to search:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/path:/search(q='anything')
```

However, it seems that the results are not limited to this folder (path). I get results for anything in my drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "fold1/subfold"

'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/' + driveId + '/root:/' + path + ":/search(q='')";
```

don't forget ":/" before "search"

Comment: Please explain your answer why it ll work by proper description and commenting.

Comment: This does not seem to work.It still searches the entire drive